# Directory is created but File is not getting created on server, local runs fine

Tags: c#, file-io, permissions

The problem with the code below is the directory is getting created on server but file is not getting created, when i run locally on my system then it runs fine, please suggest what can be done, this is my priority 1. thnx

```
public static void CreateLog(string strToLog)
    {
        try
        {
            string excepfile = "CacheServerLogs_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("-", "_") + ".txt";
            FileStream fs = null;
            StreamWriter sw = null;
            string mydocpath = "C:\\CacheServerLogs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(mydocpath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mydocpath);
            string exceptionfile = Path.Combine(mydocpath, excepfile);
            //string exceptionfile = mydocpath + "\\" + excepfile;
            if (!File.Exists(exceptionfile))
                fs = File.Create(exceptionfile);
            else
                sw = File.AppendText(exceptionfile);
            sw = sw == null ? new StreamWriter(fs) : sw;
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + strToLog);
            sw.Close();
            if (fs != null)
                fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

May be there is user permission problem but i'm trying that to.. giving folder every possible permission...

Comment: could not find the path. cannot completely log the error there

Comment: Just FYI, `File.AppendText` does automatically create the file when it does not exist, so you can simplify your code.

Comment: Please update the post with a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error was with

```
string excepfile = "CacheServerLogs_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("-", "_") + ".txt";
```

in my system the format was 22-05-2012 but on the server was 22\05\2012 so this was creating error on path not found...

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
File.CreateText or File.Write

Answer (score 0):

As you are obviously trying to write to a logfile, I usually suggest that you use a "standard" library to do so, like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).